# Appropriate statistical test to compare forest survey results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, survey-sampling

In forest regeneration, individual trees can be regularly distributed (e.g. planted in rows), randomly distributed (natural regeneration), or clumped (due to site specific failure to regenerate portions of the harvested area).  Assessors generally use fixed area plots to determine the density (number of trees per unit area) within the regenerated area, and to compare their results against a renewal standard.

Where a regulatory agency is responsible for evaluating the accuracy of the assessors results, is there a method that is robust enough to handle all 3 situations described above?  Generally, the assessors can be compelled to report on the number and size of plots used,  the mean density, and the standard deviation about that mean based on their observations.  The regulatory agency can conduct an independent assessment of the same area and compare results.

In the first two cases (regular and random distributions), a t-test to compare means seems appropriate.  In the last case, the assumption of a normally distributed population may be violated. If the variability between plots is high, a t-test may not be able to identify the situation where the 'true' result is a failure to meet the standard because the confidence limits around the mean may be so large that the regulators' result (below the standard) and the assessors' result (above the standard) are not significantly different.  Is there an alternative approach that is also relatively easy to implement and statistically defensible?

Comment: This is a good question. For those of us who don't work in this area, it might help to add (generate) a small dataset to illustrate these scenarios & what they look like.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response gung.  After further testing of the policies we are trying to implement what we have found is that we can use 'stocking' rather than total density to avoid the problem of highly clumped distributions.  The term 'stocking' refers to the number of spaces of a predefined size that are occupied by at least one tree.  Since as the stand grows, trees that are highly clumped will self-thin.  This also means that a normal distribution can be assumed in most cases.